# Mixing styles with overriden style for link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

I have two different style for links and links inside `<p>` tag.

I am using basic inheritance. And for links inside `<p>` it works ok.
But for some reason it breaks style of common links.

`active` selector applies `blue` color while it should be `red`.

See fiddle:

```css
a {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    color: red;
}

p a {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

p a:hover, a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">general link</a>
<p>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link inside p</a>
</p>
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> p a:hover, a:active {
> ```

You are misunderstanding the precedence of `,`. That means

```
p a:hover { /* foo */ }
a:active { /* foo */ }
```

**not**

```
p a:hover { /* foo */ }
p a:active { /* foo */ }
```

You want:

```
p a:hover, 
p a:active {
```